# how to set windows thumbnail toolbar in electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to add thumbnail toolbar with specified buttons in a taskbar layout of an application from it's doc. But it's showing some problem.

The main.js:

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, dialog} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow;

const isSecondInstance = app.makeSingleInstance((commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
  if (mainWindow) {
    if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore()
    mainWindow.focus()
  }
})
if (isSecondInstance) {
  app.quit();
}

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    width: 500, 
    height: 200,
    minWidth: 500,
    minHeight: 200,
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
  })
  mainWindow.setResizable(false)
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
      mainWindow.show()
      mainWindow.focus()
    })
  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
ipcMain.on('open-information-dialog', (event) => {
      if (mainWindow) {
        const options = {
          type: 'info',
          title: 'I am abled',
          buttons: ['Ok'],
          message: 'This is the way.'
        }
        dialog.showMessageBox(mainWindow, options, function () {})
      }

})
ipcMain.on('close', (event) => {
  app.quit()
})
ipcMain.on('minimize', (event) => {
  mainWindow.minimize()
})

ipcMain.on('progress', (event, per) => {
    mainWindow.setProgressBar(per)
})

  mainWindow.setThumbarButtons([
    {
      tooltip: 'button1',
      icon: path.join(__dirname, 'button1.png'),
      click () { console.log('button1 clicked') }
    }, {
      tooltip: 'button2',
      icon: path.join(__dirname, 'button2.png'),
      flags: ['enabled', 'dismissonclick'],
      click () { console.log('button2 clicked.') }
    }
  ])
```

The error:

[image]

All of my mainWindow reference working fine but when I am trying to set thumbar buttons with `setThumbarButtons()` it's getting the problem. I just try this one and I don't get any error but it's not showing any buttons on taskber window,
`The Code:`

```
app.on('ready', function(){
  console.log(mainWindow)
  mainWindow.setThumbarButtons([
    {
      tooltip: 'button1',
      icon: path.join(__dirname, 'start.png'),
      click () { console.log('button1 clicked') }
    }
  ])
})
```

I can't make any sense with this problem.

Comment: `mainWindow` is undefined. Where are you defining `mainWindow`? And are you sure it's within the scope of your code? Currently we don't have enough information or code to help you.

Comment: `let mainWindow` it's a global variable on main.js file after that I create the function at the bottom of main.js

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(mainWindow);` right before that code you posted?

Comment: `undefined` but how can I fix this.

Comment: That fact that it's `undefined` is your problem. As I said in my first comment, sadly we can't help since we don't have enough information about your code. I'd suggest making an [mcve] and editing your question to include that.

Comment: @CharlieFish I just update my full code and try another way also but it's not working for me, can you check my code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you run `mainWindow.setThumbarButtons` your window hasn't been created. Therefor `mainWindow` is undefined. Which is the error you are running into, and what it says in the error screenshot you posted.

Currently you are creating and setting your window in the `createWindow` function.

If you move your `setThumbarButtons` code into the `createWindow` function it should work.

Something like the following:

```
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    width: 500, 
    height: 200,
    minWidth: 500,
    minHeight: 200,
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
  })
  mainWindow.setResizable(false)
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  mainWindow.setThumbarButtons([
    {
      tooltip: 'button1',
      icon: path.join(__dirname, 'start.png'),
      click () { console.log('button1 clicked') }
    }
  ])


  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
      mainWindow.show()
      mainWindow.focus()
    })
  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}
```

That way you are creating the `mainWindow` first and defining it before calling that function. Otherwise `mainWindow` will be undefined which is what you were experiencing.

Comment: I just try this, it's not showing any error, also not showing any button on taskbar . When I add a consol.log(setThumbarButtons) there it's getting an error here this: https://i.imgur.com/qdJBizK.png

Comment: @Hobo That is because `setThumbarButtons` is undefined, you can't log something that is undefined. I would try setting a breakpoint to ensure that line is being run, and also looking in the dev tools to see if there are any errors there.